# Getting Counts for Twitter links, Facebook likes and Google +1 with Jquery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to get the counts for twitter, facebook and google with jquery.getJSON requests starting from the great [guide by John Dyer](http://johndyer.name/getting-counts-for-twitter-links-facebook-likesshares-and-google-1-plusones-in-c-or-php/) on how do the same with C# and PHP

actually twitter and facebook works but google don't... the json response is:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required value: id",
  "data": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required value: id"
   }
  ]
 },
 "id": "p"
}
```

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getfbcount(url){
     var fblikes;
     $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + url, function(data){;
        fblikes = data[url].shares;
        $('body').append('fb likes ' + fblikes);
     });
  }
  function gettwcount(url){
     var tweets;
     $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function(data){
        tweets = data.count;
        $('body').append('tweets ' + tweets);
     });
  }
  function getplusone(url){
     var plusones;
     $.getJSON('https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ' + 'callback=?',
        {
           "method":"pos.plusones.get",
           "id":"p",
           "params":{
              "nolog":true,
              "id":url,
              "source":"widget",
              "userId":"@viewer",
              "groupId":"@self"
           },
           "jsonrpc":"2.0",
           "key":"p",
           "apiVersion":"v1"
        },
        function(data){           
        plusones = data.count;
        $('body').append('+1 ' + plusones);
     });
  }
  $(document).ready(function($){
        var url = "http://www.google.com"
        getfbcount(url);
        gettwcount(url);
        getplusone(url);
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: you passed an invalid parameter somewhere. doublecheck some examples what you see for google+ API and make sure you formatted it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't make cross domain requests to the clients6.google.com server. you can see this in your browsers console if you leave out this part:

```
+ 'callback=?'
```

twitter and facebook allow these requests...

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need an '&' before 'callback'? At the moment it looks like you are sticking it on to the end of the key.

Answer (score 0):

As of now getting g+ count from client site is not possible . You got to do it from server side. Here is the ruby code for that .Following code returns Google Plus count of a page as json object.

```
def get_gplus_count
   google_api_url = 'https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url='
   page_url = 'http://www.linkOfThePageWhoseGPlusCountYouWant.net'
   g_count_div = '#aggregateCount'
   g_plus_count = "-1"
   begin
     content =  Nokogiri::HTML(open( google_api_url + page_url).read)
     g_plus_count = content.css(g_count_div).text
   rescue => e
   end

   render :json => { :g_plus_count => g_plus_count }
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to create a username of your page(see under your page name @username. Just click it...)

Then goto https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and get an access token key

Then script something like that

```
function facebookLikesCount(access_token, pageusername)
{
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+pageusername+"?fields=likes&access_token="+access_token+"";

$.getJSON(url,function(json){
alert(json.likes);
});
}

facebookLikesCount('your accesstoken', 'pageusername');
```

its work for me.
I never use g+ and twitter