# how to get the +1 count in google plus using any API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-one

I have tried many things but I'm not able to get a proper API which will return me the +1 count in google plus.

I have already tried using :-

[Getting Counts for Twitter links, Facebook likes and Google +1 with Jquery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929177/getting-counts-for-twitter-links-facebook-likes-and-google-1-with-jquery-and-a)

[Getting Google+ subscription count with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424640/getting-google-subscription-count-with-jquery)

[How do I get the counter of a google plus +1 button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button)

But none of them is giving me the answer.

Any thoughts....

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the counter of a google plus +1 button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button)

Answer (score 4):

i just found out a very useful site to solve our problem. :) Thanks to him!
http://99webtools.com/script-to-get-shared-count.php

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own function using [the link you and jgillich mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button/7409062#7409062). This would be slightly simplified with jQuery.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxxW4/) I made as an example. You'll probably have to use something like PHP to fetch from the site if you want to circumvent inter-domain issues. It could look something like this though (ignoring domains):

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function () {
    var url = 'https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
    $.get(url,
        function (data) {
            var aggregate = $('#aggregateCount', data).html(),
                exactMatch = $('script', data).html().match('\\s*c\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)');

            $('div').html(exactMatch ? exactMatch[1] + ' (' + aggregate + ')' : aggregate);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is an unofficial, unsupported method. It seems the URL has changed, as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button/7409062#7409062). It was working back in March.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the API does not offer any method to retrieve the +1 count. A workaround would be to fetch it directly from the +1 button like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409062/941764) (you already linked to it, but I don't think there is another way).

Answer (score 1):

this works for me :

```
var _url = 'http://mylink.com/';   
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?callback=?&url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=' + _url)).done(function(data,status,xhr){
    console.log($(data.contents).find('#aggregateCount').html());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the following for another way to get the Google+ count.

http://share.yandex.ru/gpp.xml?url=http://google.com