# Why is getting the count of shares for Google Plus extremely slow?

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-one

I use the function below which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853342/how-to-get-google-1-count-for-current-page-in-php) and at a few different places while googling on how to get the share count for a URL from Google+. The function works, as in it returns the count but the problem is that it takes about 15 seconds to get the count for a single URL. This is problematic as I load 5 articles on my homepage and they have to show the share count. I've implemented a caching solution so I don't have to go fetch the value every time but I would hate for some poor sucker to have to wait 15 seconds for a single count (let alone, 4 extra ones afterward)!

Does anyone have any idea why it's so slow and whether this is a deprecated method?

```
function get_plusones($url) {
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
      $curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
      curl_close ($curl);
      $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
      return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
    }
```

Comment: There's a solution here that you can use which is much faster:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15370750/987731