# How to get a number of Google Plus +1 for a URL of post

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I want to get a number of Google+ +1 for an URL of a article post.

For example I want to get a number of G+ like of Beautydea Magazine.
Is there a way to add my URL post for a specific URL of Google API? Such as Facebook or Twitter.
Here some examples of Facebook and Twitter with the same URL post.

Facebook:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.beautydea.it/orly-baked-collezione-smalti-estate-2014/%27
```

Twitter:

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://www.beautydea.it/orly-baked-collezione-smalti-estate-2014/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the +1 count in google plus using any API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367687/how-to-get-the-1-count-in-google-plus-using-any-api)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are doing this on the server side, you could just load the url referred to by iframe of the button

[https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.beautydea.it%2Forly-baked-collezione-smalti-estate-2014%2F](https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&url=http://www.beautydea.it/orly-baked-collezione-smalti-estate-2014/)

and read the count from the div with id "aggregateCount". You're out of luck on the client-side with that approach, since you can't load an external html page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported API method for getting the +1 count of a URL. You can star the [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=57) though.